# About server hosting, and how servers are set up

Tags: server

I have been making a game with javascript for a while now, and I am doing the websocketing with node.js and socket.io.

So my question is: Once I get a server, how would setting it up work? Would I send the people who own the server my files, and then would they take care of setting it up? Would I be able to access the computer they loaned me and set things up from there? I'm confused about the whole process... first time doing anything like this.

Comment: ovh.com   has the best valued VPN servers 2gb RAM for $3/mo ... https://www.ovh.com/us/vps/vps-ssd.xml  ... teach yourself ubuntu or better yet dual boot your laptop to boot into ubuntu ... then do on the server just what you are doing on your ubuntu laptop ... server side development introduces many new challenges to master ... I suggest you do everything yourself ... short of that checkout https://www.heroku.com/ where you can deploy your code onto their server for free ... Heroku has excellent documentation with self contained tuts

Comment: I feel as if you copy pasted that comment onto this question.

Comment: not at all ... been doing server side a very long time and have opinions that's all

Comment: fair enough, so what I gather is that you get a virtual machine and it runs "ubuntu"? Am I correct?

Comment: yes ... the path of least resistance on server side is to use ubuntu ... then you SSH onto your remote server ...  while on that server you git clone a copy your github.com repository where your code lives... launch your server then punch buttons on your client ( browser or mobile) to initiates a conversation with the server ... I suggest doing such a hello world server <--> client app ... on server side nodejs is well suited for this especially when you are using WebSockets